# The Eight Queens Problem, Alternate Solution

Tags: python

I need to know if there is a better (optimized) way of solving the Eight Queens Problem. Also, how do I insert the unicode symbol of a queen chess piece in the code?

I use Python 3.7 and made use of generators and functions to solve this problem, but somehow i don't think it is very efficient.

```
import random
def conflict(state, nextX):
nextY = len(state)
for i in range(nextY):
    if abs(state[i] - nextX) in (0, nextY - i):
        return True
return False

def queens(num = 8, state = ()):
    for pos in range(num):
        if not conflict(state, pos):
            if len(state) == num-1:
                yield (pos,)            #for tuple
            else:
                for result in queens(num, state + (pos, )):
                    yield(pos, ) + result

def readableresult(solution):
def line(pos, length = len(solution)):
    return ' .' * (pos) + ' X ' + '. ' * (length-pos-1)
for pos in solution:
    print(line(pos))

readableresult(random.choice(list(queens(8))))
```

The results are correct. It gives accurate positions of the queen pieces. There is no issue regarding the results. I want to place the queen symbol instead of the X.... How do I do it?

Comment: which symbol you like to use?please mention that symbol

Answer (score 1):

change this
`return ' .' * (pos) + ' X ' + '. ' * (length-pos-1)`
to
`return ' .' * (pos) + ' \u2655 ' + '. ' * (length-pos-1)`.

reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode